# Когда стоит наследоваться от класса?

Tags: php, ооп

Ведь можно сделать просто:

```
class DB {
    // все методы работы с БД
}

class Logger extends DB {
    // все методы логирования в БД и файлы
}

class Valirator extends Logger {
    // все методы проверки форм
}

class User extends Valirator {
    // все методы работы с юзером
}
```

И всё, я победитель по жизни, у меня в User досупны все методы всех родителей, хочу в базу пишу, логирую, проверяю. Но что-то посказывает что это неправильно.

1. Почему так как написано в коде выше это плохо?
2. По какому принципу в приложении выбирают кто и от кого должен наследоваться?

Comment: Вот советую почитать https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: @ПашаИванов этот комментарий ведёт к холивару понимания SOLID т.к. на мой взгляд в этом S соблюдается, O соблюдается, I соблюдается, а если вы мне объясните что такое L то буду благодарен, но лучше для этого создам отдельный вопрос ))

Comment: Разве ты не задавал уже этот же вопрос.. в смысле вопрос "когда стоит наследоваться". Вроде уже был и были комментарии по этому поводу

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет, там был вопрос "Когда стоит делать класс абстрактным"

Comment: @fosh4455 на самом деле суть не поменялась и всё то же самое применимо к наследованию.

Comment: Нарушается принцип единственной ответственности. Например тут "у меня в User досупны все методы всех родителей". Зачем вашему `User` уметь, да и вообще знать, про какое-то там логирование?

Comment: @rjhdby потому что если произошла какая-то ошибка (имя юзера с недопустимыми символами) её надо залогировать,хотя не очень удачный пример, в данном случае это валидатор залогирует...

Comment: а как базе данных логгировать:)? или логгер пишет в базу данных?

Comment: @fosh4455 чтобы залогировать при возникновении ошибки вызывается логгер и логирует `new Logger()->log()`.... юзеру не надо от него наследоваться.... юзер у тебя должен наследоваться как раз от какого-нибудь абстрактного

Comment: Нет. Логирование не является ответственностью User. Это как если бы вам начальник сказал "Вот тебе швабра - помой пол, а то натоптал. И не важно, что ты програмист"

Comment: @KoVadim БД в данном случае не имеет доступа к логгеру она выше него

Comment: @rjhdby, просто у тебя неправильное ООП :-D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это понятно, но так можно сделать всё и вообще не унаследовать ничего ни от чего

Comment: `на мой взгляд в этом S соблюдается, O соблюдается, I соблюдается` - ничего из этого не соблюдается.. например `S` не соблюдается потому что в итоге у тебя юзер в итоге умеет и суп варить и такси водить и нефть добывать и общаться с потусторонним миром.... `I` - не соблюдается в принципе примерно по той же причине.. потому что `I` гласит что лучше **много специализированных интерфейсов чем  один универсальный** вот у тебя юзер опять же будет уметь всё.

Comment: @fosh4455, _вообще не унаследовать ничего ни от чего_ - кстати, некоторые как раз и рекомендуют не наследование использовать, а композицию

Comment: @fosh4455 `так можно сделать всё и вообще не унаследовать ничего ни от чего` - можно. зависит от приложения. но кто сказал, что ты обязательно должен использовать всё, что имеется в ООП? нужно его применять там, где надо, а не просто ради того, чтобы это было

Comment: @Grundy композицию смотрел, у меня там возник вопрос на чём её лучше делать - на интерфейсах, трейтах, классах, пока не разобрался до конца с композицией...

Answer (score 3):

Плохого в это то, что нарушается принцип единственной ответственности. Например тут "у меня в User досупны все методы всех родителей". Зачем вашему `User` уметь, да и вообще знать, про какое-то там логирование?

Наследоваться имеет смысл если и родитель и потомок действительно являются "родственниками".

Т.е. например "Авторизованный пользователь" вполне логично отнаследовать от "Пользователь", а вот наследовать "Пользователя" от "Базы данных" - это какой-то оксюморон.

Вот так норм:

```
AuthorizedUser extends User
PrivilegedUser extends AuthorizedUser
```

А вот так нет

```
Table extends User
User extends Autobus
Autobus extends Database
```

**UPD**

С точки зрения объектного подхода к проектированию, `User` у вас - это отражение актора "Пользователь", который в принципе не должен знать о том, как устроена логика вашего приложения. `Validator`, `Logger` и `Database`- это, по хорошему, интерфейсы, а не объекты, с которыми, опять же по хорошему, `User` взаимодействовать не должен.

Рассмотрим use case - пользователь заходит в систему и по этому факту происходит его проверка и логирование.

1. Пользователь вводит логин и пароль
2. Подсистема авторизации передает в объект класса, реализующий интерфейс `Validator` введенные данные.
3. `Validator` проверяет корректность и передает объекту класса, реализующего интерфейс `Logger`, данные для логирования
4. Конкретный `Logger`, наследующий от `DatabaseSource` или `FileSource` (соответственно `DbLogger` или `FileLogger`) совершает логирование
5. Подсистеме авторизации возвращается соответствующий объект `User`, `PriveledgedUser`, `ReadOnlyUser`, etc... Либо ошибка авторизации (Exception например)

Comment: `наследовать "Пользователя" от "Базы данных" - это какой-то оксюморон.` - а как же Робокоп?) Он умел работать с БД полиции :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а он не на php писан - там множественное наследование

Comment: `наследовать "Пользователя" от "Базы данных" - это какой-то оксюморон` - у меня в рабочем проекте на котором я сейчас работаю, все классы вообще наследуются от ORM (БД фактически), писал не я, пришёл так уже было

Comment: @fosh4455 то, что оно у вас так реализовано совершенно не означает, что это правильно

Comment: @rjhdby предположу что @fosh4455 говорит  о `yii2` (могу ошибаться). там например модель генерируется `extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord`

Comment: @rjhdby так откуда ж тогда набраться хороших практик, если даже рабочий проект - самопис с велосипедом ))

Comment: @fosh4455 а ты много книг по ООП (ну и в частности PHP-ное) и паттернам проектирования прочитал?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский две

Comment: @fosh4455 обновил ответ

Comment: @rjhdby да спасибо, я отмечу решением попозже, пусть повисит денёк может ещё кто что напишет